# hadoop fs -mkdir filename, output : No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, mkdir

I am trying to make a directory using a cloud platform but instead of creating of the directory I am getting output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without an absolute path, that command creates a folder in your HDFS user's directory, which does not exist by default.

You need to start with `hadoop fs -mkdir /user/$(whoami)`, and then you should be able to create a directory as you've tried.

Or you can make directories under `/tmp`, for example instead